# Windows 8 Phone and Windows Azure Management Libraries Error

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I am newbie in Windows Phone 8 and Windows Azure Development.

I have started work on Windows Azure Management Portal on Windows 8 Phone.

I have Google a lot and found a helpful resource which is :

http://www.bradygaster.com/post/writing-a-windows-phone-8-application-that-uses-the-windows-azure-management-libraries-for-on-the-go-cloud-management

After Importing the project in VS2012 and configured according to tutorial i have found error when I am selecting  Subscription ID.

The full exception trace is below:

```
$exception  {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException: AuthenticationFailed: A security token exception occured for the received JWT token.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.WebSpaceOperations.<ListAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WamlPhone.AssetListView.<GetWebSites>d__4.MoveNext()} System.Exception {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CloudException}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious - how many subscriptions do you have? I would imagine this is happening because you either haven't selected the subscription that is associated with the WAAD tenant you're using to authenticate. OR, you've authenticated properly via the right tenant and subscription, but then try to click on a subscription that's a different subscription than the one associated with your tenant. If that's the case, this is not unusual. If you're selecting the same subscription associated with the tenant, check to make sure you've enabled the Windows Azure Management API for your app in the portal.

Comment: Dear Brady Gaster, Thanks for your response.

There is only one subscription in my azure account. And I have also enabled the Windows Azure Management API for my app in the azure portal.

I'm trying to follow your tutorial on creating an Azure management app on Windows Phone 8 from.

http://www.bradygaster.com/post/writing-a-windows-phone-8-application-that-uses-the-windows-azure-management-libraries-for-on-the-go-cloud-management

I am unable to find the root cause. Please help me out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you gotten this working? Sorry I'm lagging on the thread a bit. I'll see if I can help out any further if you're still blocked on this.

Comment: Thanks for reply brady. I am still stuck on this.

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you solve this error somehow?

Comment: Dear user2955724, Still awaiting response from  brady gaster...

Comment: @bradygaster: Brady, this error does not occur for subscriptionmanagementClient. But other management clients give this error. This is the case with many users as seen from the comment section of your blog "http://www.bradygaster.com/post/writing-a-windows-phone-8-application-that-uses-the-windows-azure-management-libraries-for-on-the-go-cloud-management". Did any one solve this?